# Using IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope() in Blazor Server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an MVC app and on one of the views I have a pretty complex Blazor calendar component which lists all accounts (workers and employers) and their availabilites / vacancies.

A lot of read/save/update DB operations are happening on that calendar and I am currently not reusing MVC services, but I create a new dbContext and have separate services for the Blazor calendar. This is because I can't use MVC Dependency Container as signalR will hate it.

Now, I have read about IServiceScopeFactory and I am wondering whether I could just reuse MVC services by creating a new scope and wrapping every method in Blazor Calendar that does some DB operation in:

```
using (IServiceScope scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{

}
```

And reusing MVC services.

Does this have drawbacks? I will probably have to call the above code on every method, but this way I can also then call my MVC services which have all the create/update methods for entities already. Will this work? Are there reasons why I shouldn't do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the IDbContextFactory, you should be fine without scopeFactory.